# Reload page every 5 seconds - external JS

Tags: javascript, refresh, settimeout, setinterval

Okay. The issue I am having is I am simply trying to do a refresh loop for my webbrowser (firefox) I would like this in JS. I understand It can be done in other languages pretty easily if you ask me. But, javascript is a must! :D This is not an html page, just a simple .js file ran with iMacros for Firefox.

Here's the code I am using.

```
            setInterval(refreshPage(), 5000);
            function refreshPage() {
                window.location.reload(1);
            }
```

window.location.reload(1); refreshes the page without a problem :D sweet!!!

But when I use the setInterval or setTimeout mumbojumbo I always get ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined...

Very strange. I Googled so hard and all searches return the same setInterval and same setTimeout options... no one is defining anything. o_O what in the world! lol

Can one of you JS WIZARDS crack this code. I need a WIZARD to save me :D

Comment: how can you refresh the page if "this is not an html page" ?

Comment: You have got the answer below, that you are using `setInterval` wrong. You also use `window.location.reload` wrong. The parameter is a boolean (if true, it will force a reload), so the correct way to do it is `location.reload(true);` see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload). There is no need to specify `window` since that is the global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are looking for

`window.setInterval(function(){refreshPage()}, 5000);`

Could also just call the function as noted in the comments:

`window.setInterval(refreshPage, 5000);`

Comment: "setTimeout is not defined..." depends on the argument how?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean.  He said he tried to use setInterval and it isn't working, and that is because he isn't using it correctly.  I answered the question for the code he provided.

Comment: i'm saying the error reported happens before the interval callback even tries to fire. if there's no setTimeout, then you can't use it no matter how you call it...

Comment: I will check mark this as the answer when allowed in 5 minutes. What a BEAST!

Comment: Why do you wrap the function in a function call? Why not just using `window.setInterval(refreshPage, 5000);`? And since the page is reloaded, using `setInterval` doesn't make sense... Better to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Just answering what he asked (his coded was showing setInterval), as for wrapping it in an anonymous function, I guess I just decided to.  You are correct I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. Your code uses `setInterval`, but your error is about `setTimeout`.

Let me assume that you want and use `setInterval` because that makes more sense as you want to refresh the page every 5 seconds.

The `setInterval` function is defined by the browser. It requires a function name as first argument. You passed in a function **call**.
To fix it, simple delete the pair of parentheses:

```
setInterval(refreshPage, 5000);
function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(1);
}
```

Comment: Technically it was the **result** of the call to the function `refreshPage` (in this case `undefined` since it do not have a return statement) that was given as the first parameter to `setInterval`.